# Flex box not vertically and horizontally centering

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm currently making an Electron app with the View powered by `Vue.js`

I currently have this (for testing purposes)

```
<template>
  <div class="formWrapper">
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <span class="inputPrepend"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .formWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .inputGroup {
    align-self: center;
  }
</style>
```

I end up with this result:

[image]

But I cannot seem to get the vertical centering to happen.

I have made sure all parent elements have a `height: 100%;` but still can't get it to go down, also why do I need to specify `align-self` if the parent flex container `formWrapper` has specified `center` for `align-items` and `justify-content`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `body` to `height: 100vh`, and `formWrapper` and all parent elements to `height: 100%`.

Live example:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.formWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="formWrapper">
  <div class="inputGroup">
    <span class="inputPrepend"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

There might be a smarter way to do this, but this is the best I could figure out.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, using 100% was dumb, should be 100vh / vw